# Add to strong together where both strings together is a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have about 15 variables named body 1, body2, body3 etc.. and I need to output their values to the representative divs which have IDs of body1, body2 etc..

Rather than having lines of code outputting it I want to do it in a loop as it’s more efficient.
This is what I have so far.

```
    for (var ii = 1; ii < 10; ii++) {

        $('#body' + ii).text( ));
    }
```

The jquery identifier of the div works fine – the issue is when I’m defining the text to put into the div.
So within the .text() bit.

I want it to increase the body variable by one like it does in the loop.
So body1 to body2 to body3 etc..

I’ve tried putting “body” + ii but as I guessed it just output “body1” to the div rather then the contents of the variable named body1.

Any thoughts?

Comment: You may want to use an array instead of having 15 different body# variables. That would be a lot easier.

Comment: As it is, you would have to use evil `eval()` like `$('#body' + ii).text( eval('body'+ii) ));`. But the root of your problem is why are you storing these 15 values as separate variables. Putting them in an array is much better and makes things like this far easier.

Comment: The eval works perfectly! Thank you. I will take your advise and move them into an array anyway. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a global variable, you can access it in "window":

```
window[variableName]
```

In your case:

```
window[body+ii]
```

but it would probably be better to store your values in an array `body` of length 15.

You can alternatively evaluate the string as code as commented by @Rhumborl

```
eval('body'+ii)
```